# PHP Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found In Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Please Help To Solve This Problem

My Controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use View;
use DB;



class MyCon extends Controller {

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Welcome Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller renders the "marketing page" for the application and
| is configured to only allow guests. Like most of the other sample
| controllers, you are free to modify or remove it as you desire.
|
*/

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Show the application welcome screen to the user.
 *
 * @return Response
 */


public function register()
{
  //return \View::make('pages.Register');
    return view('pages.Register');
}

public function RegisterAction(Request $req)
{

    $name = $req->input('name');
    $email = $req->input('email');
    $gender = $req->input('gender');
    $password = $req->input('password');
    $data = array("uname" => $name, "uemail" => $email, "ugender" => $gender, "upassword" => $password);
    DB::table('user')->insert($data);
    //return \View::make('pages.Register');

}



}
```

My Register Function work fine But When I am Submit Form ON RegisterAction function then show error like 'PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found'

My Router Code

```
Route::post('RegisterAction', 'MyCon@RegisterAction');
```

Please Help To Solve This Problem.
Thank In Advance

Comment: Why don't you just return `view('pages.Register')` instead of `View::make()`?

Comment: use `return redirect('/register');`

Comment: error show like Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: please help to solve

Answer (score 1):

as you have changed the name like this

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
```

change

```
class MyCon extends Controller {
```

to

```
class MyCon extends BaseController {
```

and you can use view helper function instead of importing View class yourself like this.

```
public function register()
{
    return view('pages.Register');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Provides a nice helper to for View class.

```
  return view('pages.Register');
```

Secondly you can also use

```
use View; //on top
View::make('pages.Register');
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Activate your APP DEBUGGER first so you can see your code issue by doing `APP_DEBUG=true` in your .env file.

including the View class in your controller won't give you an issue and restrict you to use the class or since you're using Laravel 5 you can use the function `view()` by simply calling `view('SOMEVIEWHERE')`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you redirect to a named route from route web file, try `return redirect()->route('route-name');` and if you intend to use view try `return view('view-name')`.

Using `View::class` means you are calling the view model which is not available except you have a view class created.